# generate sql file with python (for mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, escaping, character

I need to write in a txt file, sql statements with all the values escaped so I can later import it to the mysql database.

- Some background info:
  I recently created a program in python which reads a csv file and inserts the data to a remote mysql database.
  The program except the insert statements, also performs several select statements in order to collect some information such as primary keys, max ids etc.
- What I need to do in general:
  Since the whole procedure is time consuming I was hoping there is a way to write all the statements in an .sql file so then I could import it to the mysql database via PhpMyAdmin.
- What I tried and where I stuck:
  So far I can generate sql statements by concatenating text.
  But I am stuck to the point where I need to escape characters.

In SQL Server I can include any text between N'' and it will accept it as it is.. Is there anything similar in MySQL?

Example in SQL server: N'My escaped text isn't affected by single quote ->' or double quote  " '

Notice I have surrounded the text with N''.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the point in executing these queries manually? *Apparently* it will take more time than your current setup. Is there any logic behind your problem?

Comment: Why do you play with words? It doesn't change the meaning even slightest.

Comment: Sorry, it would be more correct saying "import via PhpMyAdmin" instead of "execute manually via PhpMyAdmin".

I just want to create the sql file so I can give it to another user who only knows how to import the sql file to the database.

Comment: As I said I query a database thousands of times and either I select or insert records. This slows me down a lot. Also sometimes the connection is interrupted which breaks the whole process.. and I have to start over.

This is why I need to create the .sql file locally and then upload it to PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to learn how to use prepared statements. They solve several problems for you, including escaping characters and preventing SQL injection. Here's an example with MySQLdb:

```
myValues = (value1, value2)
sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, myValues)
```

===

I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. You don't want to write a Python script that reads a file and inserts data from it into the database. You want to use Python to generate an SQL document that you can import into your database directly.

I recommend using Python to query the database, but if you really want to make an SQL document, all your data values need to be enclosed in single quotes, and if you have single quotes in your data, escape them using double single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2) VALUES ('My data', 'John''s data');
```

Other special characters such as semicolon (;) will be ignored if they're inside the single quotes.

If you're worried about special characters in the table and column names, you can add backticks to them:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ('My data', 'John''s data');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer rootbeer277.

How do I write this to a text file?

I assume the "execute" would try to execute the statement to a database, right?

Comment: You don't put the SQL statements in your text file, you put them in the Python script. The Python script then reads the text file and the prepared statement takes care of the escaping by itself. What library are you using to get Python communicating with your MySQL database? MySQLdb is popular.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I've edited my answer.